# Grayscaling OpencL c++ code error

Tags: c++, arm, opencl, gpu

I am working on OpencL grayscale code using c++. I am just a beginner in this, This is just a 2nd code from me with OpenCL. It is showing,, invalid arguments errors in enquecommands.I am not able to solve why!!? can anyone helps me in this. 
Also I would some review that is it okay? I have uses buffer instead of image objects just for the try. I will try with image objects later on.

```
const int width = 255;
const int height = 255;

std::vector<float> size(width*height,1);
std::string dev_name;

std::vector<cl::Platform> plat;
std::vector<cl::Device>dev;

try
{
    //Find OCL platform
    cl::Platform::get(&plat);
    string value;
    if(plat[0].getInfo(CL_PLATFORM_NAME,&value)!=CL_SUCCESS)
    {
        std::cout<<"No platform found"<<std::endl;
    }
    else
        cout<<"Platform found : "<<value<<endl;

    //Find device


    if(plat[0].getDevices(CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU,&dev)!=CL_SUCCESS)
    {
        std::cout<<"No device found"<<std::endl;
    }


    //Create Context

    cl::Context ctxt(dev,nullptr,0,0,&error);

    //Create CommandQueue

    cl::CommandQueue cque(ctxt,dev,CL_QUEUE_PROFILING_ENABLE);

    //Create Program

    cl::Program prog(ctxt,"/grayscake/Test1.cl",&error);

    //BuildProgram

    prog.build(dev);

    //Create Kernels

    cl::Kernel kernel(prog,"Grayscale",&error);

    //Memory Objects

    cl::Buffer input(ctxt,CL_MEM_READ_ONLY | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR,size,&size[0],&error);

    cl::Buffer output(ctxt,CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY,size,0,&error);

     //Setting Kernel Arguments

    if(kernel.setArg(0, input)!=CL_SUCCESS)
     {
         std::cout<<"Error on input arg"<<std::endl;
     }
    if(kernel.setArg(1, output)!=CL_SUCCESS)
     {
         std::cout<<"Error on output arg"<<std::endl;
     }

    //Profiling Event

    cl::Event e1;


    const cl::NDRange globalsize = width*height;


    //Enqueue Task

    cque.enqueueTask(kernel,NULL,&e1);


    std::vector<cl::Event> *profilingEvent;


    //Write to target device
    cque.enqueueWriteBuffer(input,CL_TRUE,0,size*sizeof(float),&size[0],NULL,&e1);

    cque.enqueueNDRangeKernel(kernel,0,globalsize,{2,2},NULL,&e1);

    cque.enqueueReadBuffer(output,CL_TRUE,0,size*sizeof(float),&size[0],NULL,&e1);


}
```

Comment: And you added the C tag - why? Because it starts with the same letter? Add C# and Cobol tags, too.

Answer (score 0):

Look at these lines:

```
const int width = 255;
const int height = 255;
...
const cl::NDRange globalsize = width*height;
...
cque.enqueueNDRangeKernel(kernel,0,globalsize,{2,2},NULL,&e1);
```

I think it is self explanatory. You simply can't divide a global size of 255x255 in local groups of 2x2. Select another local size or increase the global size by 1 and add a conditional in the kernel code:

```
if(get_global_id(0) < max_x && get_global_id(1) < max_y){
 ... //Your original kernel code here
}
```

Comment: Okay. Thanks. I was confused related to this stuff. But I guess this will give a logical error rather than any semantic error.
Right now, I am getting error:- Invalid Arguments for these 2 statements- 


[cque.enqueueWriteBuffer(input,CL_TRUE,0,size*sizeof(float),&size[0],NULL,&e1);]


[cque.enqueueReadBuffer(output,CL_TRUE,0,size*sizeof(float),&size[0],NULL,&e1);]

Answer (score 0):

This may be caused by not released event (cl::Event).
Try to use different cl::Event variables in each function or release event before calling another function.